# API data: Cannot read property 'slice' of null

Tags: javascript

I am getting data from SportsData NBA API and I want info about players. API returns data in this format:

```
BirthCity: "Sao Carlos"
BirthCountry: null
BirthDate: "1982-09-13T00:00:00"
BirthState: "Brazil"
College: null
```

etc.

As you can see this whole BirthDate is not what I really want, I want only the date part, excluding T00:00:00

```
 li.appendChild(
          document.createTextNode(
            `Born: ${data[i].BirthDate.slice(0, 10)} in ${data[i].BirthCity}, ${
              data[i].BirthState
            }`
          )
        );
```

I tried to fix this with slice, but problem is that not all players have BirthDate available and for some of them BirthDate returns null. So, as soon as I get to first player whose BirthDate is null, it stops working and I only get the players up to that player whose BirthDate is null.

And I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of null
    at app.js:64

Also, if a College is null, how could I for example say that player didn't go to college instead of getting null?

I used this line of code to get the College:

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`College: ${data[i].College}`));
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to check if the `BirthDate` is `null` before trying to `slice` it. Same for the `college` part.

Comment: bday = bday ? bday.slice(0, 10) : 'whateveruwant'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple logical statement to evaluate Birthdate before you attempt to `slice` it will resolve this:

```
`Born: ${data[i].BirthDate ? data[i].BirthDate.slice(0, 10) : 'Unknown'}`
```

This is called a ternary operator, and it's essentially a shorthand `if/else`. You can check out some documentation on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)